# Pandas explode with non-list column

Tags: python, pandas

I have Dataframe contain locations by string and I want to explode using them

For example, df:

| country | location | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Canda | USA,Costa Rica, | 3 |
| Italy | Germany,France,Spain | 2 |
| Russia | Israel, | 1 |

my df :

| country | location | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Canda | USA | 3 |
| Canda | Costa Rica | 3 |
| Italy | Germany | 2 |
| Italy | France | 2 |
| Italy | Spain | 2 |
| Russia | Israel | 1 |

I have a lot more then only one column such as `value` and I want to make sure they are all duplicated

Comment: Refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/a/57122617/9840637

Answer (score 1):

Split and explode

```
df['location'] = df.location.str.rstrip(',').str.split(',')
df.explode('location')
```

Output

```
  country    location  value
0   Canda         USA      3
0   Canda  Costa Rica      3
1   Italy     Germany      2
1   Italy      France      2
1   Italy       Spain      2
2  Russia      Israel      1
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm waiting the 10 min to give you the answer certificate